# Difficulty to start up with basic unit test (Sample from my book -- SportsStore)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm really new in TDD and, actually, I'm trying to follow the sample from my book (**SportsStore -- Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework/Steve Sanderson/APRESS**). I'm on pages 103-105.

Although there are more on this, as new to all of this, I'm concerned with the following statements.

```
ProductsController controller = new ProductsController(repository);
var result = controller.List(2);
     //...
```

regarding the above statements, when I write this (as in the book),

```
var products = result.ViewData.Model as IList<Product>;
```

I get a compiler error "*System.Web.MVC.ActionResult" does not contain a definition for ViewData ...*" But, when I remove the **List()** from the statement, then the compiler error disapear.

```
var result = controller.List(2);//Doesn't work
var result = controller;//It works
```

Is something wrong there? I checked Apress website for that book, but there is nothing listed as Errata or issue. **So I'm really lost.**

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because actionresult does not contains a definition for viewdata howerver viewresult does and viewresult is actually an actionresult so you can cast it to (ViewResult) and then get the viewdata

Answer (score 1):

```
var products = ((ViewResult)result).ViewData.Model as IList<Product>;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may also be missing System.Web.Mvc library from your test project

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can change the code in your Products Controller from:

```
public *Action*Result List()
{
     return View(productsRepository.Products.ToList());
}
```

to:

```
public *View*Result List()
{
     return View(productsRepository.Products.ToList());
}
```

ViewResult is a subclass of the base class ActionResult.